# How to Send Email With Attachment In Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I need to attach an image with my email in asp.net the file is already added in the solution explorer but I dont know how to add this with my email please guide me

My current code is given below

```
public void SendMail()
{
    try
    {
        string receiverEmailId = "name@exmp.com";
        string senderName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["From"].ToString();
        string mailServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"].ToString(); ;
        string senderEmailId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUserName"].ToString();
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPPasssword"].ToString();
        var fromAddress = new MailAddress(senderEmailId, senderName);
        var toAddress = new MailAddress(receiverEmailId, "Alen");
        string subject = "subject";
        string body = "body.";
        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                    Port = 587,
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, password)
        };
        using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Body = body
        })
        {
            smtp.Send(message);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Did you check out [**MailMessage.Attachments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.attachments.aspx) property (see MSDN)?

```
// create attachment and set media Type
//      see http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application.aspx
Attachment data = new Attachment(
                         "PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE", 
                         MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
// your path may look like Server.MapPath("~/file.ABC")
message.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Answer (score 10):

create object of `Attachment` class with file name and add it into message's Attachments property

```
  Attachment attachment = new Attachment("file.ext");
  message.Attachments.Add(attachment);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public static bool SendMail(string strFrom, string strTo, string strSubject, string strMsg)
    {            
        try
        {                
            // Create the mail message
            MailMessage objMailMsg = new MailMessage(strFrom, strTo);

            objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            objMailMsg.Subject = strSubject;
            objMailMsg.Body = strMsg;
            Attachment at = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("~/Uploaded/txt.doc"));
            objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(at);
            objMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            //prepare to send mail via SMTP transport
            SmtpClient objSMTPClient = new SmtpClient();
            objSMTPClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
            objSMTPClient.Send(objMailMsg);
            return true;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

[Reference](http://forums.asp.net/p/1140099/1831864.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**Sending email with attachment in ASP.Net with a simple coding. In this article I will show you, how you can do this.**

**Index.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Debug="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<title>Careers</title>
</head>

<body>
<form id="form2" runat="server">

<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputName">Name</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputEmail">Email address</label>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Email"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="txtcontact">Contact no</label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtcontact" runat="server" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact no"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="txtjobTitle">Job Title</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtjobTitle" runat="server" class="form-control">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Social Media Experts" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Business Developement Executives" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Copywriters" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Graphic Designers" Value="4"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Web Designers" Value="5"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Animation Designers" Value="6"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="txtjobExp">Experience</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtjobExp" runat="server" class="form-control">
<asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="0-1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="1-3" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="3-5" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="exampleInputFile">Upload Resume</label>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploader" runat="server" />
</div>

<asp:Button ID="bttn_Send" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="bttn_Send_Click" class="btn" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**Index.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void bttn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string from = “info@suryarpraveen-wordpress.com”;
string textTo = “careers@suryarpraveen-wordpress.com”;
using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from, textTo))
{

mail.Subject = “Careers – Surya R Praveen WordPress”;

mail.Body = string.Format(@”
Name: {0}
Email: {1}
Contact: {2}
Job: {3}
Experience: {4}
“, txtName.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtcontact.Text, txtjobTitle.SelectedItem.Text, txtjobExp.SelectedItem.Text);

if (fileUploader.HasFile)
{
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileUploader.PostedFile.FileName);
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fileUploader.PostedFile.InputStream, fileName));
}
mail.IsBodyHtml = false;
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = “mail.suryarpraveen-wordpress.com”;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(from, “password@007”);
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
smtp.Credentials = networkCredential;
smtp.Port = 25;
smtp.Send(mail);
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), “alert”, “alert(‘Message has been sent successfully.’);”, true);
}
}
}
```

https://suryarpraveen.wordpress.com/2017/08/22/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Send_Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("One@gmail.com");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("Two@yahoo.com"));
    mail.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("Three@gmail.com"));
    mail.Subject = "Testing E-mail By ASP.NET";
    mail.Body = "This is only for Demo ";

    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream ,FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);

        mail.Attachments.Add(attach);
    }


    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

    System.Net.NetworkCredential credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();

    credential.UserName = "One@gmail.com";
    credential.Password = "123456789";

    smtp.Credentials = credential;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code...

```
public void MailSend(string strfrom, string strto, string strSubject, string strBody, string resumename, string sresumename)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(strfrom, strto);// strEmail);
       
        msg.Bcc.Add("xx@xxxx.com");
        msg.Body = strBody;
        msg.Subject = strSubject;
        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        if (resumename.Length > 0)
        {
            Attachment att = new Attachment(Server.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/User_Resume/" + resumename)));
            msg.Attachments.Add(att);
        }
        if (sresumename.Length > 0)
        {
            Attachment att1 = new Attachment(Server.MapPath(VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/User_Resume/" + sresumename)));
            msg.Attachments.Add(att1);
        }
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient cli = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("111.111.111.111",25);
        cli.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("nnnnnnn", "yyyyyy");
        cli.Send(msg);
        msg.Dispose();
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "message", "alert('Inquiry submitted successfully');", true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "message", "alert('"+ex.Message+"');", true);
    }
}
```