# mail attachments using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, mailing

I am trying to mail with attachments using asp.net. To do this I have done the following code:

Default.aspx.cs:

```
using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"]);
            mailMessage.Subject = "Test Subject";
            mailMessage.Body = myString.ToString();
            if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.PostedFile.FileName);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(fuAttachment.PostedFile.InputStream, FileName));
            }
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtem.Text.ToString()));
            mailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress("sample@test.com"));
            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("sample1@test.com"));

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
            smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
            NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
            smtp.Send(mailMessage);
        }
```

Default.aspx:

```
<tr>
                                        <td align="left">Passport Scan Copy</td>
                                        <td align="left">
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="fuAttachment" runat="server" />
                                        </td>
                                        </tr>
```

Now with this code I can send email properly but there is no attachment! Is it because I have to upload the file separately in the server. Am actually clueless on this point can anyone please help me.

Comment: If that is server side code, then the files being attached must be accessible as files or in the form of a stream. If a web server this means the content must have been uploaded.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017132/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-in-asp-net

Comment: @Richard...to upload it in the server I did the following code:if (fuAttachment.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fuAttachment.FileName);
                    fuAttachment.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;
                    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
                }

            }  But it didn't uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your form enctype to multipart/form-data. Otherwise the file does not get posted to the server and your attachment will not be sent.

```
<form runat="server" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I don't have form tag in the page...its designed by site.master

Comment: You can safely add the enctype attribute to the form tag in site.master. It should not affect the behaviour of other forms.

Comment: ...I have added it but still the attachment is not going

Comment: can you put a breakpoint on this line "if (fuAttachment.HasFile)"? Is the value of HasFile true?

Comment: ...while trying to do this from a separate page the file got uploaded in the server but from this page its not uploading and surprisingly there is no error also showing

Comment: So the problem is not the code that sends the mail. The problem must be in the webform. Can you debug the page, use your browser to view the html and post the <form> tag that is rendered into the page please?

Comment: Surprisingly I just found from this code if I click on any button that is not triggering any functions...whereas there is no error its showing...shall I share those files with you here...can you please check it once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78318/discussion-between-clark-kent-and-user3305327).